# Match rows and columns of two dataframes/tibble and copy values

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, tidyverse, tibble

I have two dataframes/tibble.

The first one (initialized with zeros except for the first column):

```
> df_
# A tibble: 33 x 101
   sample_id  SOM1  SOM2  SOM3  SOM4  ..... SOM100
   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
 1 1             0     0     0     0 
 2 2             0     0     0     0
 3 3             0     0     0     0
 4 4             0     0     0     0     
 5 5             0     0     0     0     
.
.
.  33
```

The second one:

```
> sum
# A tibble: 3,300 x 3
# Groups:   sample_id [33]
   sample_id cluster_id count
   <fct>     <chr>      <int>
 1 1         SOM1         875
 2 1         SOM2        1102
 3 1         SOM3        1028
 4 1         SOM4         925
 5 1         SOM5       10164
 6 1         SOM6        5425
 7 1         SOM7        1593
 8 1         SOM8         290
 9 1         SOM9        6180
10 1         SOM10      10850
# … with 3,290 more rows
```

I want to match `"sample_id"` from `sum` to `"sample_id"` from `df_` and also match `"cluster_id"` from `sum` to colnames from `df_` and if the match is true for both the conditions then copy the corresponding value in the `"count"` column from `sum` to the cell in `df_` where the condition is found to be true. In the end, I want to replace all the zeros in `df_` with a value from the `count` cloumn in `sum`.

I want my end result to look like the dataframe below.

```
> df_
# A tibble: 33 x 101
   sample_id  SOM1  SOM2  SOM3  SOM4  ..... SOM100
   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
 1 1           875  1102  1028   925 
 2 2             0     0     0     0
 3 3             0     0     0     0
 4 4             0     0     0     0     
 5 5             0     0     0     0     
.
.
.  33
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can just use tidyverse, then `sum %>% spread(cluster_id, count, fill = 0)`

Comment: Note that you probably want to give your tibble a different name, since `sum` is a base function

Comment: Yeah, it's a temp. I will give a more sensible name. :)

Comment: @DavidKlotz btw after spread my column names are not sorted. It's like SOM1 SOM10 instead of SOM1 SOM2 ...

Comment: That's because R is ordering the columns by string, not integers.  You can manually set factor levels to override that: `sum %>% mutate(cluster_id = as_factor(cluster_id)) %>% spread(cluster_id, count, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you are trying to take the `sum` dataframe and transform it into the same view as `_df` (never call a dataframe `sum` by the way as it is one of the most common R functions).

You should be able to use this:

```
library(tidyverse)
sum %>% spread(key = 'cluster_id', value = 'count')
```